# z bar differentiation.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function $f$ defined as $\frac{\overline{z}-\overline{w}}{(z-w)(1 + z\overline{z})(1+w\overline{w})}$.

I want to prove that $\partial_{\overline{z}}^2 f + \frac{2z}{1+z\overline{z}}\partial_{\overline{z}}f = \pi \frac{2}{(1+ z\overline{z})^2}\delta(z-w)$.

I found that $\partial_{\overline{z}}f = \delta(z-w)\frac{(1+z\overline{z})(\overline{z}-\overline{w})}{1+w\overline{w}} + \frac{1}{z-w}\frac{(1+2z\overline{z}-z\overline{w})}{1+w\overline{w}}$.

If I diffrentiate again I am encountering a derievative of a delta function which I do not know how to do.

But since I know the result I calculated back what the derivative of delta function should be a found out to be $\frac{2\delta(z-w)}{\overline{z}-\overline{w}}\frac{w\overline{w}-z\overline{z}}{1+z\overline{z}}$.

Basically during the calculation I used the product rule and took $\frac{1}{z-w}$ as one function and rest as another and did the diffrentiation.I also used the fact that $\partial_{\overline{z}}\frac{1}{z-w}=\delta(z-w)$.

I would like to know whether the procedure I have done is correct.Is the derivative of the delta function I have mentioned is correct or not.Pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

The identity $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\frac{1}{z-w}=\delta(z-w)$$ is very misleading. The picture is simpler than that - at points where $z=w$ the function is not defined and there is no point in trying to differentiate it. In all other points this function is holomorphic in $z$, and so, its $\overline{z}$ derivative vanishes.